# dynamically creating buttons vs creating it through xml file (static)?

Tags: android

I am new to android programming.
I'd like to know which is a better way create ui elements like a button; defining them in the layout.xml or adding them at runtime through java like:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    mRecordButton = new RecordButton(this);
    ll.addView(mRecordButton,
        new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            0));
```

Can some one explain its pros and cons ?

Thanks
Utsav.

Comment: Do you want the button to be there during the entire activity or do you want to dynamically generate teh button..Theres your answer

Comment: You'll use XML in 99% of the cases, because you can do it visually and the Graphical Editor will take of setting all the necessary attributes. Once in a long while, you might need to add a UI element at run-time, but even that can be done through Visibility or putting dynamic buttons (i.e. lists of buttons) in ListViews or GridViews.

Comment: its mostly about versatility like in some cases you would want the user to determine the amount of certain views that come onto the screen so you would make your code load the views, some apps have a standard UI that couldnt be changed in which you could just make an XML and not have to worry about it, thats why they tell you to sit down and actually map out your whole program before you write it so you go about the correct way of doing it

Comment: alot of people extend views and make custom views witch is done in code and you can still use that in xml, its kinda like an interchangeable pallette

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visualizing the layout is a lot harder if you implement the button in code, thus making it very hard to maintain. Now in some rare cases you may need to do it in code, but it is generally not recommended. Also, localization will become a lot harder if you implement in code vs. xml files.